# C# Draw polygons using angle degrees and Trig

Tags: c#, gdi+, trigonometry

I'm trying to create simple shapes, Hexagon, Pentagon, Triangle, etc by having a starting Point and calculating where the other Points should be for each vertex. And i keep create straight lines or weird overlaping polygons. 
I use the method below to try to calculate the vertices for a Hexagon, then do a simple `graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, aptsVertices)` to draw it later.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
protected override void CalculateVertices()
{
    //member variables
    aptsVertices = new Point[6];
    deg = 120;
    rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);

    double nSinDeg = Math.Sin(rad);
    double nCosDeg = Math.Cos(rad);

    aptsVertices[0] = ptFirstVertex;

    for(int i = 1; i < aptsVertices.Length; i++)
    {
        double x = aptsVertices[i - 1].X - nCosDeg * nSideLength;
        double y = aptsVertices[i - 1].Y - nSinDeg * nSideLength;
        aptsVertices[i] = new Point((int)x, (int)y);

        //recalculate the degree for the next vertex
        deg += 120;
        rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);

        nSinDeg = Math.Sin(rad);
        nCosDeg = Math.Cos(rad);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the problem is in your `deg += 120`. Actually you need to decrease `deg` by a `step = 60°` (or increase, depending on your desired construction direction) *.

Here's the code for generic number of sides:

```
public static Point[] CalculateVertices(int nSides, int nSideLength, Point ptFirstVertex)
{
    if (nSides < 3)
        throw new ArgumentException("Polygons can't have less than 3 sides...");

    var aptsVertices = new Point[nSides];
    var deg = (180.0 * (nSides - 2)) / nSides;
    var step = 360.0 / nSides;
    var rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);

    double nSinDeg = Math.Sin(rad);
    double nCosDeg = Math.Cos(rad);

    aptsVertices[0] = ptFirstVertex;

    for (int i = 1; i < aptsVertices.Length; i++)
    {
        double x = aptsVertices[i - 1].X - nCosDeg * nSideLength;
        double y = aptsVertices[i - 1].Y - nSinDeg * nSideLength;
        aptsVertices[i] = new Point((int)x, (int)y);


        //recalculate the degree for the next vertex
        deg -= step;
        rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);

        nSinDeg = Math.Sin(rad);
        nCosDeg = Math.Cos(rad);

    }
    return aptsVertices;
}
```

### *

Subtracting the step, you will build a polygon adding sides counter-clockwise.
Adding the step, you will build a polygon adding sides clockwise.
If you want to change the inclination of your first side, just offset the initial `deg` by your desired angle.

**P.S.**
I did a static method just because was more convenient for me to test, but you can still use your instance method.

Comment: very nice, i appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

While I did not think through your algorithm; IMHO, a better approach would be to define a *central* point; and have your code calculate the other points (six, in case of a hexagon) using `point [i] = new Point (center.x + sideLength * cos ((Math.PI * i) / 6), center.y + sideLength * sin ((Math.PI * i) / 6));`.

Comment: Calculating the co-ordinates of the center point from those of the first vertex should be trivial.

Comment: if anyone is interested the page below has an algorithm that uses a central point:
http://www.vcskicks.com/regular-polygon.php

Answer (score 0):

The static function above is correct, however since it calculates the points as integers, rounding errors creep in.  Even for a 5-sided polygon, the vertex calculations will be off by a few pixels.

I substituted a Point class that uses doubles rather than integers to remove the rounding errors.  You can just round to the nearest integer when you draw the vertices.

Otherwise, the code is exactly the same.

```
public static PointD[] CalculateVertices(int nSides, int nSideLength, PointD ptFirstVertex)
{
    //calculate the points for a polygon of N sides
    if (nSides < 3)
        throw new ArgumentException("Polygons can't have less than 3 sides...");

    var aptsVertices = new PointD[nSides];
    var deg = (180.0 * (nSides - 2)) / nSides;
    var step = 360.0 / nSides;
    var rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);

    double nSinDeg = Math.Sin(rad);
    double nCosDeg = Math.Cos(rad);

    aptsVertices[0] = ptFirstVertex;

    for (int i = 1; i < aptsVertices.Length; i++)
    {
        double x = aptsVertices[i - 1].X - nCosDeg * nSideLength;
        double y = aptsVertices[i - 1].Y - nSinDeg * nSideLength;
        aptsVertices[i] = new PointD(x, y);

        //recalculate the degree for the next vertex
        deg -= step;
        rad = deg * (Math.PI / 180);

        nSinDeg = Math.Sin(rad);
        nCosDeg = Math.Cos(rad);

    }
    return aptsVertices;
}
```

This is the new point class.

```
public class PointD
{
    public double X, Y;
    public PointD(double _x, double _y)
    {
        X = _x;
        Y = _y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I recently used it, so I thought I add some modifications I added that may help some people.

I used the code above, but by using a center point to set the first vertex, and offsetting the first degree, I was able to create a polygon around a center point. I also added a method to calculate the side length, based on the radius.

Here's what I came up with (the code it's in Objective-C):

```
-(NSArray *) calculateVertices:(int)numSides center:(CGPoint)ctr{
NSMutableArray *vertices = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if (numSides < 3) {
    return vertices;
}

float deg = ((180.0 * (numSides-2) / numSides)-180)/2;

float step = 360.0 / numSides;
float rad = deg * (M_PI / 180);

double nSinDeg = sin(rad);
double nCosDeg = cos(rad);

int sl = [self calculateSideLength:numSides];

CGPoint firstPoint = CGPointMake(ctr.x, ctr.y-radius);    
[vertices addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:firstPoint]];

for (int i = 1; i < numSides; i++) {
    NSValue *vp = [vertices objectAtIndex:i-1];
    CGPoint pp =[vp CGPointValue];
    double x = pp.x - nCosDeg * sl;
    double y = pp.y - nSinDeg * sl;
    CGPoint np = CGPointMake(x, y);
    [vertices addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:np]];

    deg -= step;
    rad = deg * (M_PI / 180);

    nSinDeg = sin(rad);
    nCosDeg = cos(rad);

}

return vertices;

}

-(int) calculateSideLength:(int)numSides{
   int length = (2*radius)*sin(M_PI/numSides);
   return length;
}
```

NOTE: radius is set as a class property, that's why you don't see it being set anywhere. Also, I didn't want it throwing an exception if sides is less than 3, since I was checking for the number of sides elsewhere.

I just have a question, is it better to pass the side length as a parameter, or as I did, and call the method from within my method?